# How can I use GeoFirestore with React Native Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to implement **GeoFirestore** in my RN app but in their documentation they are not using RN Firestore library but another one:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore'; // importing geofirestore
```

... and I am using the RN library for Firestore:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore'; // importing geofirestore
```

And I am experiencing this error:

***> Error: Firestore must be an instance of Firestore***

Code that fails is below, where I am trying to query the chats which are nearby based on my location. It fails on the first line where I am initializing app with the error message above.

```
// Create a GeoFirestore reference
const GeoFirestore = geofirestore.initializeApp(firestore);

// Create a GeoCollection reference
const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('chats');

const myCurrentLoc = this.state.location[0];
const latitude = myCurrentLoc.latitude;
const longitude = myCurrentLoc.longitude;
  
const query = geocollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 20 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Geofirestore needs an instantiated firestore object. Your  script should look more like this:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore';

// Create a GeoFirestore reference
const GeoFirestore = geofirestore.initializeApp(firestore());
```